# cannot find declaration of element relativelayout when add xml from external library

Tags: android, xml, jar

im trying to use external jar file to create a ppt view in xml but it have rendering problem not showing on android studio. i pick up jar files from github
https://github.com/itsrts/pptviewer-android
but it compiles good and run in my android phone accurately just not showing the layout in android studio why is that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ahsan.islam.com.madpresentor.MainActivity" >

<com.itsrts.pptviewer.PPTViewer
android:id="@+id/pptviewer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is details of error

[Error details in xml layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKzkV.png)

Here is my **build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ahsan.islam.com.madpresentor"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',     {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/itsrts-pptviewer.jar')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is my **menifest** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ahsan.islam.com.madpresentor"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="22" android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="22" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you create a custom view, you need to override its constructors and do some logic in them. However, the IDE won't be able to instantiate your layout anymore in the preview.

To avoid that you have to check `isInEditMode()` before calling your logic in the constructors. This method only returns true when the IDE is trying to preview your layout.

Since in this case the issue happens with a third party library, there probably is nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks for response @BMacedo  but code is working fine when i rebuild and compile the project it is running perfectly on device but i want to edit layout thats where problem arise and giving such error

Comment: Yes, as I said, this only happens in the layout preview. The code will work just fine in the emulator or any device